# I tried activated the option to partition a disk, instead all my drive data disappeared in a few seconds

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, external-disk

I read online that there was a command line to activate the partition option on Disk Utility:

```
diskutil partitionDisk disk4 1 GPT HFS+ newdisk
```

Which is just supposed to unlock the possibility to partition THEN chose the partition size or erase. Instead it renamed the disk but it also made all my data disappear!!

Please tell me there's a way to retrieve it or I'm going to smash the Mac to pieces...

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Do you have a backup (e.g. Time Machine, etc)?

Comment: do not tell me you messed with disk drive without making backup ?

Comment: No I don't have Time Machine, in fact I was trying to create a partition for it but because of Disk Utility crap update I couldn't, so I entered the command line which was only supposed to unlock to option to partition.

Comment: Don’t smash the mac - it was the operator that made the error...

Answer (score 3):

diskutil partitionDisk command does exactly what you described happening.  Partitions a disk, removing all volumes.  All volumes on the disk you ran the command on are destroyed.  So you partitioned disk4 and renamed it newdisk using GPT HFS+.  I'm not sure where you got the command information from but the command you entered did exactly what it was supposed to do.  I would recommend looking into data recovery services if you need anything that was on that drive.

Comment: I'm looking into recovery app and have launched one but it'll take 18 hours. Does it allow for the recovery of the disk as is, with folders, filenames and metadatas?

Comment: I have no idea.  More information would be needed to determine if you can recovery anything but if a disk is re-partitioned it's always possible that data was written over/lost.  You may or may not be able to recover the data from the disk.